# Is the human eye supposed to see the lense effect?

Tags: human-eye, perception, experiment, cognition, optics

Just as the GoPro cameras, we need lenses to be able to focus. Nevertheless, we can see the "fisheye effect" on the shots taken by GoPros. I am talking about this:

[image: fish eye lense effect]

Is it possible to notice the "fish eye effect"? Or does the brain somehow eliminate this distortion?

[EDIT:]
My insufficient knowledge of optics tells me that, as we have lenses in our eyes, we should see the worlds through a thicker layer of mass in the middle of our field of vision, and through a thinner layer of mass on the margins of our field of vision. We know that our vision is reversed when it enters the eye. Is it inflated in the middle as well?

Is there any "distortion" in the proportions of different parts of the image (that is filtered-out at brain), or the does the image formed in retina have the proportions of different parts same as the actual scene?

Comment: Human eyes do not have the same optical properties as fish-eye lenses. As should be plain from your everyday experiences using your sense of vision, we do not see a fish-eye effect.

Comment: @MattDMo ...because the brain "filters" this effect out?

Comment: Why would the effect be there in the first place?

Comment: @AliceD Because we watch the world through lenses and there is a thinner layer of glass in the middle than on the margins.

Comment: Probably the OP is asking if there any 'distortion' in the proportions of different parts of the image (that is filtered-out at brain), or the image formed in retina have the proportions of different parts same as the actual scene.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Could you please move this question to [Cognitive science](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @MattDMo We also don't see our "blind spot," nor do we see the world upside down.  It's also hard to notice depth of field.  But we know all these things must exist because our eyes are physical optical systems.  The OP's question is a good one to ask, and I'd also like to know how the distortion (which is guaranteed to exist) gets filtered out.